# Fresh guides to build an OS on Raspberry Pi

Tags: operating-systems

I want to learn how to build an OS and thought that a Raspberry Pi would be perfect to experiment with. However, as I have no prior knowledge of building operating systems, I am looking for a guide or tutorial on how to build one. The best guide I've found so far is [this guide](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/) but it is a few years old and I'm worried that not all of the steps will work if I purchase a brand new Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Why would it not work on a newer Pi? All of the latest Pi's have been designed to be backwards compatible with the original Pi. The guide says some things may not work with the +models or the Pi 2. If its going to be such an issue the original Pi is certainly not expensive. The more Pi's the better!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some of these guides.

[armhf](https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/How-To-compile-a-custom-Linux-kernel-for-your-ARM-device) 
[Manual Build Howto](http://linux-sunxi.org/Manual_build_howto) 
[embedded-distro](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-embedded-distro/) 
[Build your own distro](https://www.linuxvoice.com/build-your-own-linux-distro/)

Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

As you have chosen RPi for the same, the following book - ARM System Developer's Guide by Andrew N. Sloss, Dominic Symes, Chris Wright and John Rayfield - should be a good option.

They explain with code on how to implement a small and simple bootloader, OS for ARM.